# Excel Pivot: % of a value

Tags: excel, pivot

How do I get a perecentage of a value in a pivot?

For example: I want the % of how many times the values Particapting and Pending show.

Table A

```
Id   Status
1     Particpating
2     Pending 
3     Null
4     Null
```

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like a pretty straightforward formula...

Comment: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot10.html#PctColumn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Pivot table for the data. Set the Rows to be Status and filter to just the ones you want. Set the Values to be Count of Id. Add a new column to the right of Count of Id with =(cell to the left)/(Count of Id grand total cell). Edit the resulting `GETPIVOTDATA` to refer to the `Ax` cell to get the Status and then copy the formula down. Reformat to be percentage.